# MySql and Visual Studio 2013 Integration

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013

Though I have been developing with Sql Server for a log time, the primary reason I wanted to move to MySql was because of some client requirement. So all the developments I have done on the front end & business logic remained the same and I just wanted to flip the database to MySql.

I had lots of problems migrating to MySql with Visual Studio especially 2013. And I spent few days figuring out how to use the extensions and Entity Model generations in this. Though this is pretty much specific to VS 2013, this can also be easily applied to 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and foremost thing that every developer would love to have is to be able to select the MySql driver from your Visual Studio while you are either generating Model classes from the MySql database or trying to manage the database from your IDE as found in the image below.

[image: MySql driver inside Visual Studio]

But this was a slightly distant from a normal reach as it is a 2 step process.

- If you do not have a MySql version installed, I heavily recommend the wamp installer which can be downloaded from http://www.wampserver.com/en/. This installs mysql, apache services and can be started with a start menu short cut. Also it runs on port 80 by default. If you want to change the port, edit the C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache_version\conf\httpd.conf file and set the port to Listen
- Install the MySql Connector for .Net with the latest version. The time when I used it, it was version 6.8.3 and worked reasonably well. Download and install it from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/  link.
- The second step is to install MySql for Visual studio and the version I used is current http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/

  After doing this, you'll be able to see the MySql driver on your Model generator.

  - In your projects do an Install-Package Mysql.Data.Entities which automatically installs the latest mysql version in your projects.
  - Replace the following web.config entries which are found as

```
    <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

```
to the following.
```

```
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></remove>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Another bug I noticed is, when you 
    - create a new Ado .net entity Model
    - Try to generate the model classes directly, it says that the Entity Framework provider is very latest and it does not have the necessary drivers for generating mysql model.

If you encounter this error, 
   - create an Ado .Net Entity model as an "Empty Model"
   - After that try to "Update Model From Database" with the connections & context names
   - If it gives the same error, rebuild/restart Visual Studio 2013 and the project. Trust me "It works this way".

Another problem I faced while moving from Sql Server to Mysql is the lower case table names (default in mysql) which eventually generates models in lower case names. To avoid this, you can set "lower_case_table_names=0" setting in C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.xx\my.ini file in the end and restart wamp. This creates tables in CamelCase and you can quickly move from Sql Server to MySql.

Also while generating the model from database, sometimes the EF wizard might hang. To avoid this, if you open & retrieve data from a table inside Visual Studio, this problem generally goes away.

Hope this helps someone save their time. If anyone find some new tweaks, please help us by sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual Studio 2012. Correct process of installing MySql will help you avoid any such error. At least this is what i did.

Download and install visual studio 2012 Download and install    mysql-installer-community-5.6.17.0 Download and install    mysql-connector-net-6.8.3 Download and install    mysql-visualstudio-plugin-1.1.1 Order is important and each item too.    Open Visual Studio and Create new project Add reference of MySql.Data    in solution explorer after right clicking the project name View    server explorer Add new connection and fill the spaces correctly At    the top of your code, add using MySql.Data.MySqlClient